# Retrieve "link" location from google maps website in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, hyperlink, location

I am interested in retrieving this type of link from maps.google.com https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rInK.jpg
At the moment, I have an app that calculates lat & long, and reverse geocodes it into a real address by connecting to the net.  I want the corresponding link (as in picture above) of this location.
Can anyone advise how I could go about this?  I have not seen a similar request.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the lat,lon its really pretty easy to reverse engineer the URL

> http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&geocode=&q=26.234235235,133.12312412

The last two double values are the lat,lon footprint